# Python importing (in Flask)

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I am trying to setup a way that 2 people can work on one flask project without having conflict

In flask framework, the url response is like following:

in ~/application/urls.py

```
from flask import render_template
from application import app
from application import views

app.add_url_rule('/function1', view_func=views.function1)
```

in ~/application/views.py

```
def function1():
    #something here
return
```

in ~/application/__init__.py

```
import urls
#and other things
```

Now what I want to do is to have 2 coders,
each person writes his/her own coder_urls. and coder_views in their own files

And then in the main urls.py and views.py I just import them from the files so the 2 coders can code separately and I can easily combine them.

I am guessing: coder1_urls.py

```
import coder1_views
app.add_url_rule('/coder1/function1', view_func=coder1_views.coder1function1) 
#this may need change
```

coder1_views.py

```
def coder1function1():
    #something here
    return
```

similar to coder2.

How do I do this? 
How should I arrange the files and write imports for my main urls/views files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in several ways. I would suggest two of them.
First suggestion: Create a *coders* package containing the coders modules

```
~/application/__init__.py
~/application/coders/__init__.py
~/application/coders/foo.py
~/application/coders/bar.py
~/application/views.py
~/application/urls.py
...
```

You can import the coders functions in the *views* module:

```
from application.coders.foo import foo_coder_fucntion
from application.coders.bar import bar_coder_function
```

Second suggestion: Create a *views* package and dedicate a module view to each coder

```
~/application/__init__.py
~/application/views/foo.py
~/application/views/bar.py
~/application/views/main.py
~/application/urls.py
...
```

In the module you start the flask application:

```
import application.views.foo
import application.views.bar
import application.views.main
```

I prefer the first one.